# Use jQuery instead of html frames to display the selected page from menu bar without reloading in same page

Tags: jquery

Since HTML frames are out of date I want to use JQuery .Can this be achieved by any other methods.

Comment: You can use jQuery `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` to retrieve remote resources, then handle and render the response anywhere on the page. You will find plenty of online examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using any AJAX implementation. jQuery is one such implementation which can asynchronously load page content without reloading the entire page.

A basic example of how you could implement this with jQuery would be something like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page3">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Welcome page....</p>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function(){
                // When you click on an anchor in the #menu
                $("#menu a").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault()
                    //Get the content from the page in the anchor herf
                    $.ajax({
                        url:$(this).attr('href'),
                        method:'POST',
                        async:true,
                        complete: function(xhr){
                            //set the innerHTML of #content with the file content
                            $('#content').html(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your page files, you would only have the content you wanted to load in the target of your ajax call:

```
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<p>This is page 1...</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Exactly what I was looking for.