# javascript: make a POST call on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post, buttonclick

I want to make a `POST` on button click by adding an event listener to it, but with ajax I can make the call but I do not have any data or success, error criteria for the same.

one way I found was using form submit event, but I guess it is not the right way to do it, I should be making a POST call on button click.

```
<div id="googleSignInDiv" class="cols-row ">
   <form id="googleSignInform" action="/connect/google" method="post"
      target="google-auth-window">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-sub-action  gss-col-12 type-300 social-button google" 
         id="signin-login-google-button" >
      <span class="icon social-icon"></span>
      <span class="btn-label">
      {{[loc-signin-google]}}
      </span>
      </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

If I do something like this in my `onclick` function, its not working as desired, neither am getting any error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/connect/google',
    type: 'POST'
});
```

And after this, I have my code to open the new window. How can I make a post call and mark its target as the `google-auth-window` which I have defined in my code? or using the form is the correct way?

Comment: You need to add details to your $.ajax() call to handle any response from your POST handler. For a basic on click ajax example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345039/use-jquery-instead-of-html-frames-to-display-the-selected-page-from-menu-bar-wit/49345154#49345154

Answer (score 5):

The default behaviour of a button of type `submit` in a form is to submit it, so you have to prevent the default behaviour first by using `event.preventDefault()` and followed by what you desire to do on click of the button (ex: validations etc.). In your case you can call the function that makes the AJAX call (`makeAjaxRequest`). Your code will look something like this:

```
$("#signin-login-google-button").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  makeAjaxRequest();
});
function makeAjaxRequest() {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/connect/google',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        //code to open in new window comes here
      }
  });
}
```

On success of the ajax call you can write code to open it in a new window. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030686/4445511) for the same.

Comment: well this is not solving the problem, in this particular case, the call is never going inside the success block.
I think instead of ajax I need to do plain HTTP POST , I am not sure how

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is not about how to handle `Ajax` calls, rather how to integrate google user login with user and not doing by submitting the form but should be done async. (Correct me I am wrong :) )

I think the if you follow google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), you might see that google already provides a library in (`platform.js`) for handling it via ajax and also opens it in a seperate form.

With it you can have a google login button with only

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

and it opens a window for login and return backs to your callback url provided in you configuration on Google APIs.

Let me know if you get stuck anywhere. :)

Comment: thanks, though it looks a good solution, I am afraid won't be suitable in my use case as we have a service in place which is written in a specific way, and implementing it  this way would be like building again everything